# Trying to make a group of fields required on combobox selection in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

In Access 2010.

I have 3 separate groups of fields that can be active based on a combobox selection but I'm trying to get them to be required as well. I've looked everywhere but it doesn't appear to be any VB code to make a field required. Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

The code I have right now to make the selected group of fields active and make the one's not selected blank:

```
Private Sub Combo109_Click()

If Combo109 = "Germ" Then
cg_moisture.Enabled = True
cg_oil_nir.Enabled = True
extraneous_material.Enabled = True
fines.Enabled = True
cg_moisture.Enabled = True
cg_oil_nir.Enabled = True
extraneous_material.Enabled = True
fines.Enabled = True
Moist_cgm_nir.Enabled = False
prot_cgm_nir.Enabled = False
oil_cgm_nir.Enabled = False
meal_color.Enabled = False
load_out_temp.Enabled = False
moist_cgf_nir.Enabled = False
prot_cgf_nir.Enabled = False
oil_cgf_nir.Enabled = False
profat_nir.Enabled = False
starch_nir.Enabled = False
total_sug_nir.Enabled = False
loadout_temp.Enabled = False
screen_thrus.Enabled = False
screen_thrus.Value = ""
Moist_cgm_nir.Value = ""
prot_cgm_nir.Value = ""
oil_cgm_nir.Value = ""
meal_color.Value = ""
load_out_temp.Value = ""
moist_cgf_nir.Value = ""
prot_cgf_nir.Value = ""
oil_cgf_nir.Value = ""
profat_nir.Value = ""
starch_nir.Value = ""
total_sug_nir.Value = ""
loadout_temp.Value = ""
screen_thrus.Value = ""
screen_thrus.Value = ""

End If
```

Comment: By 'required', I assume you mean you want the fields to contain values? And from the looks of your code, you have enabled 21 fields. Is data required in all 21? There are ways to validate what you are looking for, but I just need to understand the exact problem/question.

Comment: So for this particular piece of code, if "Germ" from Combo109 is selected, the top 8 fields on this code are enabled (all fields are disabled on the form load). I also need them (the fields that are enabled) to be required or contain values before the user can create the record. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF all of the controls are in the 'Detail' section of your form, AND if a contrtol is Enabled, you require a value, then the code below should work. If you want more meaningful names to be displayed, either change your control names, or place a better name in the control 'Tag' field and reference that. The following code only checks Textboxes and CheckBoxes - modify to suit your needs.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim ctl         As Control
Dim blnMissing  As Boolean
Dim strMissing  As String

For Each ctl In Me.Section("Detail").Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Enabled = True Then
            'Debug.Print ctl.Name & vbTab & ctl.Value
            If ctl.Properties("Enabled") = True Then
                If Me(ctl.Name) = "" Or IsNull(Me(ctl.Name)) Then
                    blnMissing = True
                    strMissing = strMissing & ctl.Name & "; "
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
If blnMissing = True Then
    MsgBox "You are required to enter data in fields: " & strMissing, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Required Data"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question. Is there a way to exclude a certain field from this bit of code?

Comment: Yes, multiple ways. 1. by checking for the field by exact name or part of the name; 2. by placing some value in the field.tag property (i.e. 'skip') and checking the tag value. The check could be placed anywhere in the above code.